# How to plot data with different lengths in a boxplot with mpl and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I usually use R to do statistics but I am about to learn python and pandas and numpy.

I have a df that i created myself containing different times (in days). I calculated them in advance, an opening date and (in the last col) a number give some info about the set.

This is a part of the df. (dft)

```
  Freigabe Fauf  Transport/Auslagerung  Qualitätsprüfung  Packen  Auslieferung  Gesamt  Komp Werk
0       2018-11-29                    1.0              27.0     2.0           2.0    31.0          0
1       2018-11-30                    0.0              28.0     1.0           2.0    31.0          0
2       2018-06-05                    1.0               9.0     7.0           1.0    17.0          1
```

Now I want to split it up, I used masks to seperate the months in the frame.

```
m1_mask = dft["Freigabe Fauf"].dt.month == 11
m1df1 = dft[m1_mask]

m2_mask = dft["Freigabe Fauf"].dt.month == 06
m2df2 = dft[m2_mask]
```

Now I have two different dataframes with different lengths.
I want to plot the times columnwise.

For example "Gesamt" of the first and second df in a boxplot to see how the "Gesamt"-times have changed over time.
In R I simply used a list and the default boxplot-function because R can handle vectors of different length in a list.

```
my_list = [m1df1["Gesamt"],m2df2["Gesamt"]]
```

This is how i could imagine it in python but it does not work. How could I handle it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python boxplot out of columns of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144071/python-boxplot-out-of-columns-of-different-lengths)

Comment: In my case I do have different boxplots (in real 4 different months and the last months split up in 4 weeks) that I want to merge columnwise back into one dataset to create the boxplots. That means I need several dataset for each "Transport", ...., "Gesamt". Boxplots seem to be impractical becasue as far as i understood they are better with  columns of same length

Comment: Do you want to recombine the filtered data into one df? Could you show an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[['Gesamt']].groupby(df['Freigabe Fauf'].dt.month).boxplot()
```

Output:

[image: output(1)]

Or, similarly, with `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
df['month'] = df['Freigabe Fauf'].dt.month
sns.boxplot(x="month", y='Gesamt', data=df)
```

Output:

[image: output(2)]

Or if you want to use only 2 DataFrames that you created:

```
z = pd.concat([m1df1, m2df2])
z = z[['Gesamt']].groupby(z["Freigabe Fauf"].dt.month).boxplot()
```

**Update:**

To plot boxplots for the last month split by week:

```
df['month'] = df['Freigabe Fauf'].dt.month
z = df[df['month']==df['month'].max()] # data for the last month
z = z[['Gesamt']].groupby(z["Freigabe Fauf"].dt.week).boxplot() # plot weekly boxplots for the last month
```

Comment: thanks works for me! As i see you built up a new df constructed from the monthly dfs and just plot them "monthly". Thanks I didnt think so far now my next step is to find the same solution for my weekly reports. But that will wokr out too!

Comment: Cool! You can also do the same thing to have weekly boxplots with `df['Freigabe Fauf'].dt.week` (instead of `df['Freigabe Fauf'].dt.month`)

Comment: Added "Update" section to my answer with how to filter the last month and plot it weekly